# After closing the navigation bar in mobile, it's not showing in the desktop design

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a state called "isOpen." When I click the hamburger button(FiMenu), it sets the isOpen state to the opposite. It works exactly as I want it, but if I close the hamburger menu and resize my screen to desktop anymore, the navbar is not showing. Can I add a condition like "If screen size is larger than mobile, then no matter what, just show the navigation bar"?

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

<FiMenu className="md:hidden" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
      <ul
        className={`${
          isOpen ? "text-2xl md:flex gap-10 text-center" : "hidden"
        }`}
      >
</ul>
```

isOpen state : false
Mobile preview
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6bZN.png

isOpen state :true
Mobile preview
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX3xS.png

isOpen state: false
Desktop preview
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P5r8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a logic mistake from me; I updated like this:

```
<FiMenu className="md:hidden" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
      <ul
        className={`${
          isOpen
            ? "text-2xl md:flex gap-10 text-center"
            : "hidden text-2xl md:flex gap-10 text-center"
        }`}
      >
</ul>
```